# SQL count rows from two different tables where both have same foreign key from entirely different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Main
(MainId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
Name nvarchar(50))

CREATE TABLE Foo
(FooId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
MainId int,
FooAnotherColumn int,
FOREIGN KEY (MainId) REFERENCES Main(MainId)
)

CREATE TABLE Bar
(BarId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
MainId INT,
BarAnotherColumn INT,
FOREIGN KEY (MainId) REFERENCES Main(MainId)
)
```

I want count from boo and bar tables with Name = something. Here is the query I have came so far.

```
DECLARE @fooCount int, @barCount int;

SELECT
    @fooCount = (SELECT
        (COUNT(*))
    FROM Foo o
    INNER JOIN Main s
        ON o.MainId = s.MainId
    WHERE s.Name = 'something')

SELECT
    @barCount = (SELECT
        (COUNT(*))
    FROM Bar o
    INNER JOIN Main s
        ON o.MainId = s.MainId
    WHERE s.Name = 'something')

SELECT
    @fooCount + @barCount;
```

Is this can be optimized?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance, your queries probably have the best plan.  You can combine them into a single query:

```
SELECT f.foocount + b.barcount, 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as foocount,
      FROM Foo o INNER JOIN
           Main s
           ON o.MainId = s.MainId
      WHERE s.Name = 'something'
     ) f CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as barcount
      FROM Bar o INNER JOIN
           Main s
           ON o.MainId = s.MainId
      WHERE s.Name = 'something'
     ) b;
```